# UPDATE & SELECT & INNER JOIN combined (SQL92) — How?

Tags: join, select, update, filemaker

I have two tables with the following columns:

```
Table1
id 
Sort
dou
```

and

```
Table2
id_Table1
Sort
```

and I need to read all values of Table1.Sort where Table1.dou = 1 and write them into Table2.Sort, into those rows where Table2.id_Table1 matches the Table1.id values.

I can do: `SELECT Sort FROM Table1 WHERE dou = 1`

And I can do `UPDATE Table2 SET Sort WHERE id_Table1 = 'uuid'`

But how can I combine these in a way that all Table1.Sort values overwrite the Table2.Sort values?

In my version of SQL92 I can use `INNER JOIN` statements, but I don’t know how close it adheres to the standard. I have no idea this could work with an `UPDATE` statement.

I'm using FileMaker SQL engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ANSI SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) 13.9 page 391, an UPDATE using JOIN is NOT part of the standard.

You could use a correlated subquery.

Qyery,

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET Sort = ( SELECT Sort 
             FROM Table1 
             WHERE Table1.id=Table2.id_Table1 
             )
```

---

Update join different dbms

[SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET  Table2.Sort = Table1.Sort
FROM Table2 t2 
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.id=t2.id_Table1
```

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
SET  t2.Sort = t1.Sort
FROM  Table1 t1
WHERE t1.id=t2.id_Table1
```

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) / [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/)

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.id=t2.id_Table1  
SET  t2.Sort = t1.Sort
```

---

The following qyery was used by OP and solves the problem

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET Sort = ( SELECT Sort 
             FROM Table1 
             WHERE Table1.dou = 1 
             AND Table1.id = Table2.id_Table1 ) 
WHERE Table2.dou = 1
```

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot!  I added one line your suggested query and now it works: UPDATE Table2 
 SET Sort = ( SELECT Sort
  FROM Table1
  WHERE Table1.dou = 1
  AND Table1.id = Table2.id_Table1
 )
 WHERE Table2.dou = 1